# add new to Transactional email template backend is not working

Tags: email, email-templates

Transnational email template i cant edit in on backend nor i can't add new template page goes blank white page in backend its working fine on local environment but not on live server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was extension conflict with extension that magento hackathon email preview after removing this extension email template start working properly
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/E-MailPreview